# Devise logs users out after hitting certain routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is my routes files:

```
Tubalr::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root :to => "application#index"

  get "/player/:search_type/:search/:first_video" => "application#player"

  get "/just/:artist_band.json" => "api#just"
  get "/similar/:artist_band.json" => "api#similar"
  get "/:username/favorites.json" => "api#userFavorites"

  get "/just/:artist_band" => "application#index"
  get "/similar/:artist_band" => "application#index"

  get "/history" => "application#history"

  get "/:username/favorites" => "favorites#init"

  post "/check-favorites" => "favorites#check"
  post "/favorites/add" => "favorites#add"
  post "/favorites/remove" => "favorites#remove"  

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
end
```

The routes `/history` and the default `/users/edit` route for devise do not log the user out.

I'm not sure what other information to give, if theres something that would help debugging my problem, please let me know and I'll update the question.

The entire projects code can be found here: https://github.com/cjstewart88/Tubalr/tree/user_favorites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around I finally ran into this:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/913

It appears that the csrf token needs to be passed along with AJAX request, which my app is doing a good bit.